# Can we measure macroscopic objects with width atom precision?

Tags: solid-state-physics, measurements, length

Can we measure a length of a macroscopic object, like the length of an edge a piece of steel, with atomic level precision, in the sense that we could measure the length of the edge of a crystal precise enough to determine the count of layers it is long?

An example for macroscopic precision would be a gauge block, which is build to have an precise length and surface, and is commercially available up to any precision that is commercially feasible.

(They are so smooth that they can be stuck together by hand so they stick together surprisingly well. They are used by sticking various sizes together for precise length measurement).

Comment: this might be relevant https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanometrology#:~:targetText=Nanometrology%20is%20a%20subfield%20of,accuracy%20and%20reliability%20in%20nanomanufacturing.

Comment: One can measure _changes_ in the length of the LIGO arms with extreme precision: about $10^{−18}$ m, less than one-thousandth the diameter of a proton.

Comment: A so-called _[scanning tunneling microscope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanning_tunneling_microscope)_ can be used to map out the locations of individual atoms on the surface of a solid object. Its resolution as a measuring stick can be just a fraction of the distance between the individual atoms.

Answer (score 1):

There was an effort to redefine the kilogram with a "perfect sphere" of silicon. The form error is about 20 nm.
https://www.imeko.org/publications/wc-2015/IMEKO-WC-2015-PL-002.pdf